# Проверить, какое получилось число

Tags: ассемблер

Здравствуйте. Начал изучения ассемблера, но столкнулся с проблемой вывода числа на экран:

```
assume cs: code, ds: data
data segment
    a dw 10
    b dw 20
    c dw 5
    x dw ?
data ends

code segment

start: mov ax, data
    mov dx, ax
    mov ax, a
    sal ax, 1
    add ax, a
    mov bx, b
    add bx, 5
    sar bx, 1
    add ax, bx
    sub ax, c
    dec ax
    mov x, ax
    mov ah,9
    mov dx, x
    int 21h
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Здесь происходят разные вычислительные операции, и итог записывается в переменную `x`. Почитав, я понял, для того чтобы вывести строку на экран, нужно поместить строку в регистр `dx`, вызвать функцию вывода `mov ah,9` и потом прерывание `int 21h`. Но это про строки, а с числами это не выходит. И как я почитал, чтобы перевести число в строку, придётся постараться и там уже использовать стек, я до стеков ещё не дошёл. Можно ли как-то посмотреть память или что-то вроде того?

Comment: Если чисто для отладки, то почему бы тогда просто не воспользоваться API функциями, предоставляемые системой. Так, в случае с Windows, это WinAPI

Comment: Чисто для ознакомления с результатом, чтобы понять, правильно ли я написал команды вычислительные, подскажите, пожалуйста, какие именно функции WinApi можно использовать и как?

Answer (score 1):

[[@iproger](/users/1720/iproger)](/users/1720/iproger), чтобы просто просмотреть, можно использовать Turbo Debugger.

По поводу вывода. Если изучаете ассемблер для себя, советую изучать сразу под Windows (или Linux, смотря какая у вас основная система). Тогда можно будет пользоваться теми функциями, которые предоставляет операционная система. И лучше не TASM, а MASM32 или FASM.

Comment: В это дебаггере ничего непонятно, где именно найти значение какой-либо переменной. Вот пишет регистр dx с нужной мне переменной: 66A6, насколько я понимаю это адресс памяти, а как мне по этому адресу значение получить?

Comment: @iproger, если вы смотрите на регистр dx *после* выполнения, например, строки `mov dx, x`, то в нем должно быть значение из переменной, а не адрес. Если до выполнения - то там будет "мусор".

Comment: да после выполнения смотрел, в итоге регистры заменил на подрегистры: ax на al, bx на bl, и тп - в дебаггере стало норм отображаться значение!)